# Eliminar traza excepcion en test JUnit correctos

Tags: java, excepciones, junit

Estoy probando la funcionalidad de un codigo por medio de JUnit y no se como "eliminar" una traza cuando lo que estoy probando es que se imprima esa traza , no se si me explico , adjunto un ejemplo :

```
@Test
public void ejemploTest(){
 try{        
   funcionAProbar();
   fail("deberia haber saltado una excepcion");
 }catch(ExcepcionSaltada e){
  //nada
 }
}
```

Ese test funciona correctamente pero en la consola sigue imprimiendo la traza de la excepcion clasica

```
ExcepcionSaltada :Error while...
Caused by: comm.exceptions.RequestException: The ....
at .internal.comm.CommChannel.checkReturnValue(CommChannel.java:209)
at internal.comm.CommChannel.requestOp(CommChannel.java:152)
at comm.data.access.DataAccessService.requestOp(DataAccessService.java:181)
... 33 more
```

en el logger .
 ¿Hay alguna manera de evitar la traza de la excepcion en la consola ?

Muchas gracias !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es probar que una excepción es lanzada lo puedes hacer así:

**En JUnit 4:**

```
@Test(expected = ExcepcionSaltada.class)
public void ejemploTest(){
    funcionAProbar(); // Función que lanza la excepción
}
```

Si necesitas saber el texto exacto que lanza la excepción debes crear una regla (@Rule):

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException exceptionRule = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void ejemploTest() {
    exceptionRule.expect(ExcepcionSaltada.class);
    exceptionRule.expectMessage("Mensaje de la excepción esperado");
    funcionAProbar(); // Función que lanza la excepción
}
```

**En JUnit 5:**

```
@Test
public void ejemploTest(){
    Exception exception = assertThrows(ExcepcionSaltada.class, () -> {
        funcionAProbar(); // Función que lanza la excepción
    });

    String expectedMessage = "Mensaje de la excepción esperado";
    String actualMessage = exception.getMessage();

    assertTrue(actualMessage.contains(expectedMessage));
}
```